# java.lang.NullPointerException nesse código

Tags: java, swing, thread, nullpointerexception

Esta dando erro java.lang.NullPointerException, nessas duas classes.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PrimosPanel extends JPanel { 
    private JTextField tf1, tf2;
    private JButton b1, b2, b3;
    private JTextArea ta1;
    public PrimosPanel() { }
    public JButton getButton1() { return b1; }
    public JButton getButton2() { return b2; }
    public JButton getButton3() { return b3; }
    public JTextArea getTextArea() { return ta1; }
    public JTextField getTextField1(){ return tf1; }
    public JTextField getTextField2(){ return tf2; }

}
```

Classe sem thread

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class PrimosST extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private PrimosPanel pp; //componente de interface
    private boolean stop; //variável de contole de processamento
    public PrimosST() {
        super("Primos sem Thread");
        setContentPane(pp = new PrimosPanel());
        pp.getButton1().addActionListener(this);
        pp.getButton2().addActionListener(this);
        pp.getButton3().addActionListener(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 150);  
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==pp.getButton3()) {
            try {
                pp.getButton2().setEnabled(false);
                pp.getButton3().setEnabled(false);
                calcPrimos(Integer.parseInt(pp.getTextField1().getText()),
                           Integer.parseInt(pp.getTextField2().getText()));
                pp.getButton2().setEnabled(true);
                pp.getButton3().setEnabled(true);


            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                pp.getTextArea().setText("Intervalo invalido!");
                return;

            }
        } else if(e.getSource()==pp.getButton2()) {
            pp.getTextArea().setText(null);

        } else {
           stop = true;
            pp.getButton2().setEnabled(true);
            pp.getButton3().setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void calcPrimos(int inicio, int fim) {
        pp.getTextArea().setText("Calculando:\n");
        stop = false;
        for(int n = inicio; n<=fim && !stop; n++) {
            int i;
            for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
                if(n%i==0) break;
            if(i==n) pp.getTextArea().append(n + ",");
            }

        pp.getTextArea().append("\n");
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     new PrimosST().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Erro `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PrimosCT.<init>(PrimosCT.java:16)
    at PrimosCT$2.run(PrimosCT.java:71)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Classe com thread

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PrimosCT extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private PrimosPanel pp;
    private boolean stop;
    public PrimosCT() {
        super("Primos com  Thread");
        setContentPane(pp = new PrimosPanel());
        pp.getButton1().addActionListener(this);
        pp.getButton2().addActionListener(this);
        pp.getButton3().addActionListener(this);
        setSize(300, 150);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e ) { stop = true; }

        } );
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==pp.getButton3()) {
            try {
                pp.getButton2().setEnabled(false);
                pp.getButton3().setEnabled(false);
                new Calculo().start();

            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                pp.getTextArea().setText("Intervalo invalido!");
                return;
            }   
        } else if(e.getSource()==pp.getButton2()) {
            pp.getTextArea().setText(null);
        } else {
            stop = true;
            pp.getButton2().setEnabled(true);
            pp.getButton3().setEnabled(true);

        }
    }
 public void calcPrimos(int inicio, int fim) {
 pp.getTextArea().setText("Calculando:\n");
 stop = false;
 for(int n= inicio; n<= fim && !stop; n++) {
     int i;
     for(i=2; i<n; i++)
         if(n%i==0) break;
     if(i==n)pp.getTextArea().append(n + ", ");

  }
 pp.getTextArea().append("\n");
 }
 private class Calculo  extends Thread { //clase interna
     @Override
     public void run() { //adiciona cálculo
         calcPrimos(Integer.parseInt(pp.getTextField1().getText()),
                   Integer.parseInt(pp.getTextField2().getText()));
         pp.getButton2().setEnabled(true);


     } 
 }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new PrimosCT().setVisible(true);
        }
    } );
}
}
```

Erro: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PrimosCT.<init>(PrimosCT.java:16)
    at PrimosCT$2.run(PrimosCT.java:71)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você pode ver no seu *stack trace*:

```
at PrimosCT.<init>(PrimosCT.java:16)
```

a exceção ocorre na linha 16 da sua classe `PrimosCT`, que é a linha `pp.getButton1().addActionListener(this);`. A exceção é lançada pois o `getButton1()` está retornando nulo.

Em sua classe `PrimosPanel` você declara vários elementos mas não inicializa eles. Você deveria inicializá-los por exemplo dentro do construtor da classe. Exemplo:

```
public PrimosPanel() {
    tf1 = new JTextField();
    b1 = new JButton();
    //inicializa todos os elementos
}
```

Comment: Ainda continua dando erro de compilação.

Comment: @LeonardoOliveira mas o stack trace mudou? Até então foi possível identificar um problema, o NPE, talvez tenha mais.

Comment: @LeonardoOliveira pus seu código para rodar e ele foi normal, inicializando todos os componentes dentro do construtor, portanto não há mais erro na compilação. Mas o programa em si não faz nada, pode haver erros de lógica nele.